How to prove this inverse inequality about boundary flux when using FEM?
I'm currently studying the article by Pehlivanov et al.:
Pehlivanov, A. I.; Lazarov, R. D.; Carey, G. F.; Chow, S. S., Superconvergence analysis of approximate boundary-flux calculations, Numer. Math. 63, No. 4, 483-501 (1992). ZBL0797.65079.
However, I'm having trouble understanding the proof of Lemma 3.1 in the article.
Lemma 3.1:
Let $S = S(\Omega, h)$ denote a strip of elements in $T_h$ with each element having at least one vertex on $\Gamma$ and let $v_b\in V^b_h$. Then
$$ |v_b|_{1,h}\leqslant Ch^{-\frac{1}{2}} \Vert v_b\Vert_{0,\Gamma},$$
$$ |v_b|_{0,h}\leqslant Ch^{\frac{1}{2}} \Vert v_b\Vert_{0,\Gamma},$$
where $\Omega=\cup_{K\in T_h} K$ (i.e. the domain is covered by finite elements exactly) and
$$X_h=\{v(x)\in C^0(\Omega):v(x)|_K\in P_1(K),K\in T_h\}.$$
And the subspaces of $X_h$:
$$ V_h=\{v\in X_h:v=0\ \text{ at the corner of}\ \Omega\},$$
$$ V_h^b=\{v\in V_h:v=0\ \text{at the interior nodes of}\ \Omega\}.$$
The article mentions that the proof of this lemma is "quite obvious," but I am struggling with it.
I am familiar with the inverse inequality$$ |v_b|_{1,h}\leqslant Ch^{-1}\Vert v_b\Vert_{0,h},$$
so if I could establish that $|v_b|_{0,h}\leqslant Ch^{\frac{1}{2}} \Vert v_b\Vert_{0,\Gamma}$,the proof would be complete. Could someone guide me on how to prove the estimate
$|v_b|_{0,h}\leqslant Ch^{\frac{1}{2}} \Vert v_b\Vert_{0,\Gamma}$?

Firstly, from a quick look at the paper, it's worth highlighting that $\Omega$ is a polygon and $\Gamma$ is it's boundary. Furthermore the notation $|v_b|_{1,h}$ here is a semi norm defined just over $S$ and not all of $\Omega$. I'll denote this $|v_b|_{1,S}$ for clarity.
You already appreciate that $|v_b|_{1,h}\le Ch^{-1}\|v_b\|_{0,h}$ comes from the equivalence of norms on finite dimensional spaces, a scaling argument and the quasi optimality of the mesh. It also
holds locally, I.e. $|v_b|_{1,S}\le Ch^{-1}\|v_b\|_{0,S}$. Therefore the inequality $|v_b|_{0,S}\le Ch^{1/2}\|v_b\|_{0,\Gamma}$ also follows similarly, provided that $\|v_b\|_{0,\Gamma}$ is a norm on $V_h^b$ (to see the scaling argument, just look at how it plays out with $v_b=1$ as a toy example).
The axioms of a norm that are clear immediately are homogeneity and the triangle inequality (both coming from being an $L^2$-type norm). The only other part to prove is positive definiteness $\|v_b\|_{0,\Gamma} 
=0\iff v_b=0$. The direction $\Leftarrow$ is obvious, and the other implication comes from the definition of the space. We see that $\|v_b\|_{0,\Gamma} 
=0\Rightarrow v_b|_\Gamma=0$, which means that
$v_b$ is zero on all vertices of the mesh, and therefore must be zero as it is already continuous and piecewise linear.
